# Python Skipping Unittests

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have Python 2.7 selenium unit tests that need to run in a particular order and if one test fails inside a class, there is no point in running the remainging tests in that class. I know this is bad and the tests should run independently.

In the code below, I'm trying to use test_a to set bar=False so that test_f gets skipped. This is not working for me and I was trying to figure out why.

```
from unittest import TestCase, main as unittest_main, skipIf


class TestSimpleFoo(TestCase):
    foo = 'bar'
    bar = True

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_a(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.__class__.foo, 'bar')
        self.__class__.foo = 'can'
        # can i skip test_f ???
        self.__class__.bar = False

    @skipIf(bar == False, "skipping")
    def test_f(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.__class__.foo, 'can')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest_main()
```

Comment: I would suggest raising an error inside the test that you think is being skipped just to be sure that it is being skipped.

Comment: You should perform the skip check inside the test case method, and then raise `unittest.SkipTest(reason)`.

Comment: In this case, I'll go inside the test and check for my condition and use `self.fail('Reason')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, this doesn't work when `test_a` is run before `test_f`?

This is normal behavior, as the condition is tested when the decorator is constructed, which is before `test_a` is executed (when the unit test classes are registered).

It feels like you want to deactivate tests if previous tests are broken, but this is not the proper way of doing so.